# How to change the Markers label text color?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, label, google-maps-markers

I have the problem that the label will stay black even with the labelColor property in JavaScript but i want to have it white is there any way to do so? Maybe a workaround?

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: labels[i],
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelColor: '#fff',
    labelInBackground: false,
    icon: locations[i][4]
});
```

The problem is that I have custom icons that I want to use and I don't want to create some SVG first. 
Thanks to anyone who can help me here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set the label properties for a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) you need to use a [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel) object:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  map: map,
  label: {
    text: 'A',
    color: 'white',
  }
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: 'A',
      color: 'white',
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to check ".labels" class in CSS, maybe you should to change color in css file.

Comment: Oh im sorry i could have add that to my post but the css is fine allready tried both ways just not working for me :/